# Business days calculation (by including time portion) between start date and end date by excluding weekends and custom/business specific holidays

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Could you please help me out how to calculate the no. of business days between start date and end date by excluding weekends & business specific holidays. Let's say if we take start date, end date and custom holiday table with list of holiday dates as mentioned below.

**Start date (mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss)** : '10/15/2012 08:00:00'

**End date (mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss)**   : '10/23/2012 10:30:00'

**holiday_table.business_holiday_date values (mm/dd/yyyy)**:

10/17/2012

10/19/2012

10/22/2012

Need to calculate business days by taking into consideration of the time portion of dates in the calculation (so can expect business days with fractions as well ex. 1.25, 3.7 etc)

Appreciate if you can help me on this ASAP.

-James

Comment: Hello James and welcome to StackOverflow. Consider expanding your question with what have you attempted so far. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT(end_date - start_date) - 
(select count(*) 
 from holiday_table 
 where business_holiday_date >= start_date
 and business_holiday_date <= end_date)
FROM dual
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e7a5/7) is a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that use only 2 dates but you can improve it. Here you go...

1. First check how many days you got in the holiday table, excluding weekend days.
2. Get business days (MON to FRI) between the 2 dates and after that subtract the holiday days.

   ```
   create or replace
   FUNCTION calculate_business_days (p_start_date IN DATE, p_end_date IN DATE)
           RETURN NUMBER IS
           v_holidays     NUMBER;
           v_start_date   DATE   := TRUNC (p_start_date);
           v_end_date     DATE   := TRUNC (p_end_date);
           BEGIN
           IF v_end_date >= v_start_date
           THEN
                   SELECT COUNT (*)
                   INTO v_holidays
                   FROM holidays
                   WHERE day BETWEEN v_start_date AND v_end_date
                   AND day NOT IN (
                           SELECT hol.day 
                           FROM holidays hol 
                           WHERE MOD(TO_CHAR(hol.day, 'J'), 7) + 1 IN (6, 7)
                   );

           RETURN   GREATEST (NEXT_DAY (v_start_date, 'MON') - v_start_date - 2, 0)
                +   (  (  NEXT_DAY (v_end_date, 'MON')
                        - NEXT_DAY (v_start_date, 'MON')
                       )
                     / 7
                    )
                  * 5
                - GREATEST (NEXT_DAY (v_end_date, 'MON') - v_end_date - 3, 0)
                - v_holidays;
           ELSE
                   RETURN NULL;
           END IF;
   END calculate_business_days;
   ```

After that you can test it out, like:

```
    select 
            calculate_business_days('21-AUG-2013','28-AUG-2013') as business_days 
    from dual;
```